# Which Anti-Virus companies share their signature databases?

Tags: antivirus, antimalware, detection

I recently heard that AVG and AVAST shared their malware signature databases ([avast forum](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=199495.0))

Which AV vendors share their signature databases or use the same engine for detecting malwares? Based on your experiences or exact proof from the vendors.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but they share signature databases because Avast owns AVG.